# How can I use flexbox to achieve a tabular look with vertically aligned columns and zebra shading?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using the following to implement vertically aligned columns using flexbox:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbzv9efv/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0.3em;
}
.column > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div>food</div>
    <div>beans</div>
    <div>macademia nuts salted and coated with caramel</div>        
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div>comments</div>
    <div>beans</div>
    <div>excellent nutrition</div>                
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div>price</div>
    <div>3$</div>
    <div>20$</div>                
  </div>            
</div>
```

... the above works nicely but when I try to add zebra shading the margins between the colors become visible as shown [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbzv9efv/1/).

How can I use flexbox to achieve a tabular look with vertically aligned columns and zebra shading?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kbzv9efv/2/ ? And add few more borders. Or, rather use display:table, for tabular look? :)

Comment: I don't know whether you will love it or not, but you can achieve the same thing with bootstrap table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `margin` use `padding`.

Apply the padding only to inner columns:

```css
/* KEY RULE */
.column + .column > div {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

/* ORIGINAL CODE */
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.column > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div>food</div>
    <div>beans</div>
    <div>macademia nuts salted and coated with caramel</div>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div>comments</div>
    <div>beans</div>
    <div>excellent nutrition</div>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div>price</div>
    <div>3$</div>
    <div>20$</div>
  </div>
</div>
```